# CakePHP Ajax Pagination - Scroll Top once new page clicked

Tags: ajax, cakephp, pagination

When using the Ajax Pagination in CakePHP, it works fine, except it would be nice when clicking on next, or a different page number, if the page were to scroll to the first record.  At the moment, the page reloads, but continues to stay at the bottom of the page.  Is there a fix for this?

I have seen this:
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");

But am not sure how to implement this in the Pagination call, e.g:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#content'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide some Javascript in 'before' & 'complete' to all Ajax calls, these will be called before the Ajax call and on completing the Ajax call.

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#content',
    'complete' => '$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");'
));
```

Comment: Awesome stuff - this is exactly what I was after!  Thanks so much :)